# R bar plot with 3 variables

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataframe that has multiple variables, and I would like to know how can I plot them like the plotting option in `Excel`.

Just a simple data example:

```
  > V1   V2  V3
    1    A    0
    1    A    0
    1    B    1
    1    B    0
    1    A    1
    2    A    0
    2    B    0
    2    A    0
    2    A    0
    2    A    0
```

What I'd like to have, is an `x` axis with `V1`, a `y` axis with all the count of `V3` when `V2` is `A` or `B`.

Can somebody please share some thoughts on how to do this? The `barplot` function doesn't seem capable because it can only work with `2*2` table?

Thank you.

Edit:

This plot is not generated by the data given though:
[image]

Consider the `y` axis as the percentage of `V3`, the `x` axis of `V1` and for each level of `V2` a bar chart is created.

Comment: I may be numb to Excel, but can you draw or show an example of the final figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library( 'ggplot2' )
library( 'reshape2' )
df1 <- dcast( data = df1, formula = V1 ~ V2,  value.var = 'V3',  fun.aggregate = sum )  # get sum of V3 by grouping V1 and V2
df1 <- melt( data = df1, id.vars = 'V1')   # melt data
df1
#    V1 variable value
# 1  1        A     1
# 2  2        A     5
# 3  1        B     1
# 4  2        B     0  


ggplot(data = df1, aes( x = factor( V1 ), y = value, fill = variable ) ) +    # print bar chart
  geom_bar( stat = 'identity' )
```

[image]

using `position = 'dodge`

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes( x = factor( V1 ), y = value, fill = variable ) ) +    # print bar chart
  geom_bar( stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge' )
```

[image]

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 'V1   V2  V3
    1    A    0
                  1    A    0
                  1    B    1
                  1    B    0
                  1    A    1
                  2    A    0
                  2    B    0
                  2    A    0
                  2    A    5
                  2    A    0', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

Comment: Thank you! But does `ggplot` have a "beside" option like the `barplot` does, so I don't get stacked bars but bars next to each other?

Comment: Thanx! When I tried to reproduce it, I get "could not find function ".fun"" when running `dcast`?

Comment: Hi @Sathish after re-start it's still the same. But I'm sure this is a problem with the package and function, and not with you code. Thank you a lot! =)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get a summary `dataframe` that contains the values you want to plot.

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = rep(1:2,each=5), V2 = c("A","A","B", "B", "A", "A", "B","A", "A", "A"), 
                 V3 = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0))

values <- aggregate(df$V3, list(V1 = df$V1, V2 = df$V2), sum)

#    V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  A  1
# 2  2  A  0
# 3  1  B  1
# 4  2  B  0

ggplot(values, aes(x = factor(V1), y = V3, fill = V2))+
                geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.2)
```

[image: one]

OR, this if you don't want them to be stacked on top of each other. Adding some labels.

```
ggplot(values, aes(x = factor(V1), y = V3, fill = V2))+
                geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.2, position = "dodge") +
                labs(list(x = "x", y = "count",fill = "group"))
```

[image: two]

**EDIT**

I tried to use `ggplot` directly on the `dataframe` without making a summary, and the results are the same.

```
## a little change in V3
df <- data.frame(V1 = rep(1:2,each=5), 
                 V2 = c("A","A","B", "B", "A", "A", "B","A", "A", "A"), 
                 V3 = c(2,0,1,2,1,3,3,8,1,0))
## plot df directly
ggplot(df, aes(factor(V1), V3, fill = V2)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.2, position = "dodge") +
        labs(list(x = "x", y = "count",fill = "group"))
```

[image: three]

Comment: Thank you @Misaki!